# Sonarqube Provide link in widget description

Tags: sonarqube

I want to provide the link to my widget's documentation in the description.
Right now, I put the link in the `@Description` annotation and it's shown as plain text.

Is there a way to make the link clickable?

Maybe a `@Link` annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible. But we have an open ticket about such an improvement => http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5674